# cannot remove or reinstall mysql and other packages after recent upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, mysql

upon upgrade I keep receiving problems with one package name ampagent. Neither can be removed nor reinstall. Now the problem expanded to other. Here are the information when I hit `apt-get autoremove`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lightdm (1.18.2-0ubuntu2) ...
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service AMPAgentBootup and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service AMPAgentBootup at depth 3
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service AMPAgentBootup and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service AMPAgentBootup at depth 3
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up ampagent (6.4.180-1) ...
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service AMPAgentBootup and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 8
insserv:  loop involving service AMPAgentBootup at depth 3
insserv: Starting AMPAgentBootup depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ampagent (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm
 mysql-server-5.7
 ampagent
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: ampagent is a dell toll as it reveals https://support.software.dell.com/k1000-systems-management-appliance/kb/114887

Answer (score 0):

**NOTICE: It's Work In Progress**

A quick search reveals that `ampagent` is a Dell System Management Tool.

You can try uninstalling it from terminal using

```
sudo opt/dell/kace/bin/AMPTools uninstall
```

as suggested by them. https://support.software.dell.com/k1000-systems-management-appliance/kb/114887

After un-installation finishes, issue `sudo dpkg --configure --all` and `sudo apt-get -f install` command to fix remaining problems.